# Why is my Majesty palm getting dried out, when the soil is moist and I'm misting the foliage daily?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, overwintering, dryness, palm

I recently repotted my Majesty palm and pruned the fronds that were damaged in the past.
It all looked really nice and fresh, and I've been misting it every morning.

However, I lately realized that some of the  fronds were turning lighter in color, and some were drying out, like it went through an oven or something.

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misting is not an effective way to raise the humidity around a plant unless you are in a greenhouse. The amount of time the humidity is raised is very small.

Try checking the soil and watering when the top inch is dried out.  [Capillary matting or a wicking system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/how-do-i-make-the-water-reach-the-roots-on-a-pvc-aquaponics-system/4002#4002) is a great way to see that the plant gets the water it needs, but not too much.

Palms are noted for getting [spider mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/what-is-wrong-with-my-lemon-tree/8568#8568). Check under the leaves for small white dots the size of a grain of salt.  They can be controlled with soap and water applied at least three times at five to seven day intervals.

Edit: The plant in the picture is not dry but I am trying to remove all the possible problems.  I suggest you remove the plastic wrap around the base.

Edit: the die back on the leaves does not look like fungal/viral activity as there are no spots or necrotic areas. It could be burn from high salt levels in the soil or shipping damage from being exposed to cold air when brought from the store.

When watering check that the entire root ball gets enough water, check for insects, place in a sunny location.

Edit: filtered tap water is fine for most tropicals. Yes you can cut off the dead part of the leaves, leave a thin margin of dead material at the end of the trimmed leaf.

Comment: so are you saying this drying out  is from under watering? Also see the top of the new leaf it got wrinkle is that also from under watering?

Comment: its not a plastic wrap just the info lable it came with but no prob i'll remove it as soon as I get home.

Comment: as you can see from the last pic that I just took. most of the fronds are simply getting dried out Is this a lost case and return it,or can this still be saved?

Comment: ok i'll make sure that the entire rootball gets watered. will it harm the plant if i would trim off the dried parts or will it get better on its own?

Comment: sofar i have only watered with filtered tap water should i use another source for the water?