# Small brown scales on my lemon tree

Tags: diseases, pests, citrus, lemons, scale

My small lemon tree has been showing these scabs for a while. They are brown, mm sized, and fall off very easily just touching them with a finger or a nail. Examining the soil with a lens I also noted some tiny white mites, but they don't seem to climb on the plant and neither produce any web.

I've been using a generic insecticide but I didn't note any improvement.
Sould I try with some water+soap solution as suggested here: [What is wrong with my lemon tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/what-is-wrong-with-my-lemon-tree)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see here for another picture and answer http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4549/499

Comment: This one too: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/what-are-these-hard-white-brown-spots-growing-on-my-houseplant I think that we got it