# How to maintain indoor Polyscias fruticosa

Tags: indoors

I have a little plant of Polyscias fruticosa in my living-room. It is about 1 m tall and more then 10 years old. It is not exposed to direct light.

Last year it started to look a bit painful and, indeed, its root were starting to rot. I changed its soil, adding some sand to it, to drain water.

After one year, it is still alive, but still very painful: very few leaves, not of that usual, beautiful, dark green color. Also, since some years, it is not flowering. It also used to have a strong scence of liquorice, that now is almost unnoticeable (I must admit that this last consideration could be just an impression).

Any suggestions to make it feel better?

Note: I already checked a similar questions (e.g.: [What kind of tree is this?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20542/what-kind-of-tree-is-this) ) about Polyscias fruticosa, but replies to it do not actually address my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of tree is this?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20542/what-kind-of-tree-is-this)

Comment: most houseplants get too much water and not enough light. Can you provide a picture?

Comment: Thanks for checking that other question. It really helps to know you've ruled it out. Is it the same variety though? I agree with kevinsky about pictures, since we can't see what you can!  Have you moved it since it's been sick? Are leaves dropping off or just not growing new ones? When was the last time it had flowers? Are there any roots coming out of the bottom, which could mean the pot's too small? Thanks!

Comment: I'll provide a picture as soon as possible. Meanwhile: the variety looks the same. I've never moved it. Leaves DO drop, but I think it is OK: it used to drop lot of leaves, replacing them with new ones. Probably not many new leaves are now replacing the old ones. It had flowers for the last time some years ago (I think about 4-5 years ago), in summer. No roots are coming from the bottom. It looks like no new stuff (roots, leaves, branches, etc.) is coming from from anywhere, instead. Thanks!